# VC++ Interop DLL: Binary was not built with debug information

Tags: c#, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, interop, com-interop

I have a VC++ (.exe) application built in Visual Studio 2019. In project properties I have set to generate debug information for it.

```
Configuration Properties --> C/C++ --> Debug information format --> Program Database for Edit and Continue (/ZI)
Configuration Properties --> Linker --> Debugging --> Generate Debug Info --> Generate Debug Information (/DEBUG) (Also I have tried here: Generate Debug Information optimized for sharing and publishing (/DEBUG:FULL)
```

In the output it generates three files:

```
myApp.exe
myApp.pdb
myApp.Interop.dll
```

Now from another C# app I launched this VC++ exe app by using Process.Start("myapp.exe") in order to communicate between them later.

Now I am trying to debug C# and VC++ apps so I open two instances of VS, one for each app.
From VS I start debugging the C# app and from the another VS I attach to the process VC++ app. In the VS where I have launched my C# app, in modules window I can see below message:

```
C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\C23J1LN6.XOZ\GJPNWB74.YC1\bdcce8ba\10fb0e7d_e918d801\myApp.Interop.dll --> Binary was not built with debug information
```

Why isn't it capable to find my myApp.pdb file that was generated? all myApp.* are in the same directory.

Comment: @AlexF myApp.* files are not located in AppData. Instead they are located in another directory from which I start myApp.exe using Process.Start.

Comment: @AlexF Well myApp.Interop.dll.pdb does not exist. It only exists myApp.pdb. I don't know how myApp.Interop.dll.pdb can be generated. Also I don't know why it is trying to load pdb from myApp.Interop.dll.pdb¿?¿?¿? instead of loading it from myApp.pdb

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an issue with the debugger type that you are using in the solution with the C# project. Visual Studio will default to "Managed only" when debugging a C# project. However, you want to debug both the C# project and the associated C++ dll. When trying to load the symbols for a native application / shared library it will fail as if there were no valid symbols.

Depending on how you attach to the C# executable:

- if you are starting the executable directly from Visual Studio, you need to check "Enable native code debugging" in the Debug tab of your project properties [1];
- if you are starting the executable externally and only later attaching using Visual Studio, you need to select "Native" and "Managed" clicking on the Select button in the "Attach to" row.

#### References

- [1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-managed-and-native-code#configure-mixed-mode-debugging
- [2] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-in-mixed-mode